# PHP 7 php-devel package is required - phpize

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7

I'm trying to get MongoDB up and running on my server. I have the mongo database setup and it runs from ssh (I can create and query databases). But now I'm trying install the PHP library. I'm running PHP Version 7.0.5 and have tried "sudo pecl install mongodb" I get the error

```
Starting to download mongodb-1.1.6.tgz (653,403 bytes)
..................................................................................................................................done: 653,403 bytes
350 source files, building
running: phpize
Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

However, when I go to `/usr/bin/` I indeed have `phpize` there.

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I believe i have this. How do I download and install the one for php7.0.5?

Comment: You need to use your environment's package manager to install the "php-devel" package. E.g. apt-get, yum, etc.

Comment: then i get 
Error: Package: php-devel-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1
           Installed: php-5.4.45-53.el6.art.x86_64 (@atomic)
               php(x86-64) = 5.4.45-53.el6.art
           Available: php-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (base)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
           Available: php-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm trying to upgrade my libs from 7.2 to 7.4 on centos and getting exact same error when running `pecl upgrade timezonedb` on 7.4. When I try to install php-devel it says the libs (old php libs) conflict with the 7.4 libs installed